# Generate a typed enum in C# using CodeDom

Tags: c#, enums, codedom

I'm trying to figure out how to generate a typed enum with CodeDom (in C#).

Specifically, something of the form:

```
// Create an enum that supports long integer values.
enum Days : long {Sat=1, Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri};
```

I can generate a regular enum easily enough by setting the IsEnum property on the CodeTypeDeclaration to true, but I need to initialize some of the member values to numbers that wont fit into the int type (which seems to be the default for enums in C#).

Any help would be much appreciated!

Edit:
For anyone looking for info on how to create a basic enum:

```
CodeTypeDeclaration enumType = new CodeTypeDeclaration("MyEnum");
enumType.Members.Add(new CodeMemberField("MyEnum", "First"));
enumType.Members.Add(new CodeMemberField("MyEnum", "Second"));
enumType.Members.Add(new CodeMemberField("MyEnum", "Third"));
```

The InitExpression property can be used to set the actual value of each enum member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a base type for the Enum by using the `BaseTypes` property like this:

```
CodeTypeDeclaration enumType = new CodeTypeDeclaration("MyEnum");

enumType.IsEnum = true;

enumType.BaseTypes.Add(typeof(long));

enumType.Members.Add(new CodeMemberField("MyEnum", "First"));
enumType.Members.Add(new CodeMemberField("MyEnum", "Second"));
enumType.Members.Add(new CodeMemberField("MyEnum", "Third"));
```